# How to make the UIImage filled with an irregular shape?

Tags: ios, image

I want to the UIImage filled with an irregular area, not crop, not mask. Make image deformation.

What should I do ? use CoreImage?

[image]

Comment: `UIImageView`s are rectangular. I think you'd accomplish this by rotating the frame. I'm not an expert, but I'd start looking here. http://radar.oreilly.com/2013/07/rotating-a-uiview-in-3d.html

Comment: @AdrianB, i was thinking the same thing... I think that link answered the question.

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: I need help, I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

`UIImageView`s are rectangular. I think you would accomplish this by rotating the frame on its axes. You would make use of the `CABasicAnimation`. Since your question is fairly general, I can't give a specific answer, but I would point you in this direction.

http://radar.oreilly.com/2013/07/rotating-a-uiview-in-3d.html